# C# ListView - control checkBox event

Tags: c#, listview, controls

Suppose I need to change the status of an item from active = true to active = false and vise versa and at the same time persist my change in the database table.

I tested ItemChecked event like the following:

```
    private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)sender;

        if (item != null)
        {
            Book b = (Book) item.Tag;

            b.MakeActive(item.Checked);
        }
    }
```

I failed.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)sender; will throw an exception if its an invalid cast so you will need to change that line to ListViewItem item = sender as ListViewItem; if you want an invalid cast to return null

Comment: Please describe how you fail. Do you get an exception - what do you expect to happen, what happens?

Comment: private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)e.Item;

            if (item != null)
            {
                if (item.Tag != null)
                {
                    Teacher t = ((Teacher)item.Tag);
                    t.TeacherGoesToLeave(item.Checked);
                }
            }            
        }

I became successful this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this case `object sender` is `ListView` and not `ListViewItem` your code should be this

```
private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
   ListViewItem item = e.Item as ListViewItem;

    if (item != null)
    {
        Book b = (Book) item.Tag;

        b.MakeActive(item.Checked);
    }
}
```