# Checked items in C# Listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a Listview control in C# application filled with some names and checkboxes to select one or more value. Apart from clicking on checkboxes, user can also click on the name and it will become blue. I want to keep this functionality as clicking on the name shows some more data and clicking on checkbox marks it for further processing

I believed that clicking on checkbox changes Item.Checked property and clicking on name Changes Item.Selected but it seems to be no so simple.

I have a code that counts checked items:

```
private void Listview1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e) 
{
    foreach(ListViewItem Item in ListView1.Items) 
    {
        if (Item != null) 
        {
            if (Item.Checked == true) N++;
        }
    }
    Textbox1.Text = N.ToString();
}
```

When user clicks checkboxes there is proper number displayes but when he clicks name, the checked number changes to 1 even if there are still more checkboxes checked, which is obviously wrong. Also when the form and the control load, I get my N=1 even if there are no checkboxes checked.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Thanks for quick response and useful hints!

And I've just discovered that my problem was my negligence  as I forgot to remove my old code! :) 
At first I used multiple selection to pick up items, then I  switched to checkboxes but still was calling SelectionChanged event and modifying textbox content

Comment: Where is N initialized? In the event code, N is not set back to 0 to restart counting.

Comment: I hope N is not 1 b4 u r getting into the loop :)

Comment: @Yogendra: Please use proper spelling. We are not in a script kiddie chat here.

Comment: Oops, noted, newbie here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# ListView - control checkBox event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976569/c-sharp-listview-control-checkbox-event)

Answer (score 5):

To get the number of checked items in a `ListView` control, use the `ListView.CheckedItems.Count` property.

Example:

```
int numCheckedItems = myListView.CheckedItems.Count;
```

or

```
TextBox1.Text = myListView.CheckedItems.Count.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not iterate trough all items as `ItemCheckedEventArgs` provides all info you need:

```
private void Listview1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e) 
{
    ListViewItem item = e.Item as ListViewItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
       if (item.Checked) 
       {
           N++;
       }  
       else
       {
           N--;
       }
    }
    Textbox1.Text = N.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `ListView` with event `ItemChecked` is `Winforms` so no `ViewState` involved :)

Answer (score -1):

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   
    SelectEmployeeBLL selectEmployeeBLL = new SelectEmployeeBLL();

    int employeeId = Convert.ToInt32(employeeNameInsertComboBox.SelectedValue);
    
    int departmentId= Convert.ToInt32(departmentNameInsertComboBox.SelectedValue);

    bool departmentNameCheck = selectEmployeeBLL.DepartmentNameDuplicateCheck(departmentId, employeeId);

    if (departmentNameCheck)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Department already have");
        return;
    }


    SelectEmployee selectEmployee = new SelectEmployee();
    selectEmployee.DepartmentIDID = departmentId;
    selectEmployee.EmployeeIDID = employeeId;
    

    bool aselectEmployee = selectEmployeeBLL.SelectEmployeeIsert(selectEmployee);
    if (aselectEmployee)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("save successfull");
        LoadEmployeeDepartment();
    }
}
```